add member in pyrogram does not work properly
I have written a script to add members to the Telegram group. Function add_members() return true but memebers not added in my telegram group ,How can I fix the problem?
async def add(client,id , chatid ):
  global addcount
  try:
      noww = await client.add_chat_members(chatid, id)
      print(noww)
      if noww == True :
        addcount = addcount +1
        print(f"added member = {addcount}")
      await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(8,12))
  except FloodWait as e:
      print(f"i need to sleep {e.value} second")
      await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(8,12))
  except UsernameNotOccupied:
    print("username not Found!!")
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6,10))
  except UserNotMutualContact:
    print("User Not Mutual Contact!!")
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6,10))
  except PeerFlood:
    print("Account limited !!")
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6,10))
  except ChatAdminRequired:
    print("admin!!")
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6,10))

from 40 true add_members() only 1 user added in my telegram group.
I expected using the function add_member() can add a lot of user in group!

A few things need to be checked before adding, like rate limit, permissions, Member Restrictions, etc.
Please try this code to get a better understanding of the exception/error.
import asyncio
import random
from telethon.errors import FloodWait, UsernameNotOccupied, UserNotMutualContact, PeerFlood, ChatAdminRequired

addcount = 0

async def add(client, user_id, chat_id):
    global addcount
    try:
        result = await client.add_chat_members(chat_id, user_id)
        print(result)
        if result:
            addcount += 1
            print(f"Added member = {addcount}")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(8, 12))
    except FloodWait as e:
        print(f"FloodWait: Sleeping for {e.seconds} seconds")
        await asyncio.sleep(e.seconds)
    except UsernameNotOccupied:
        print("Username not found!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))
    except UserNotMutualContact:
        print("User not a mutual contact!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))
    except PeerFlood:
        print("PeerFlood: Account limited!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))
    except ChatAdminRequired:
        print("ChatAdminRequired: Admin privileges required!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))


Do you have any suggestions for checking permissions , like rate limit , member restrictions?

I am not familiar with these. Please refer to API doc.
